# Improving dynamic list selection

Tags: lists, selection, hierarchy

I have the problem related in this link for a desktop app:

[Suggestion for list selection and populating related lists dynamically](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52157/suggestion-for-list-selection-and-populating-related-lists-dynamically/53340)

but instead of 3 list I have 7 and some lists have more than 20 items to choose. I like the idea of showing the next list only after a item is selected.
The problem that I have is the layout. It takes too much horizontal space if more than 4 items are selected. Is there any other way to organize this?
I don't like a lot the accordion solution, because only two first selections are required and I have to create accordion options dynamically. It isn't a web app and interface components are hard to code.

Comment: What sort of thing is someone selecting? What's the use case?

Comment: They are internal classification options related about vehicles. First list are vehicle type (car, bus,..), second are vehicle parts (motor, brakes,..) and so on. Some options have up to 7 selections.

Comment: Regarding your use case, I'm doubting if a list is the best option to show the information. Having a list with 20+ items to pick from is a lot of items. Perhaps a searchable dropdown might be better.

Comment: I agree, but it's a user requirement. How can I show/edit that without a list?

Comment: Was it a client requirement or a user requirement? Did the user ask for lists or did the user ask for the current flow of information (So that you see the next section after you have selected a categorie).

Comment: User don't ask for a list, he only want to choose between selection options. For me a nested lists was the most obvious way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The use case isnt completely clear, but if a cascading menu isnt appropriate due to horizontal real estate - maybe you can use a wizard like approach and change the panel's contents based on the current step.

Selecting an option on the list will advance the user automatically to the next step.

You should provide the user an option to go back in steps and change the selection, but future steps will not be available until all steps before have been completed. 
[image]

Comment: Interesting. And how show all options selected when users aren't editing?

Comment: Add a title with each option appended to it as the user moves through.

Comment: The same question applies for a cascading menu. Depends on the end result of these selections. If it results in a list of items - you can display the applied filters using a left panel.

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine what are you and Darryl say. Can you post and image, please?